# Where is the local static variable stored? If it is data segment, why its scope is not whole program?

Tags: c, static

If static local variable also stored in the data segment, why can't values are not persist for variable which is used in two different functions. example like this.

```
void func()
{  
    static int i=0;
    i++;
}

void func1()
{
 i++; // here i is stored in the data segment,
       // then the scope should be available for entire program 
}
```

Why the value 'i' is only accessible to block scope if is stored in data segment? it might be a silly question but I am trying to understand to concept. Please help me to understand concept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Because the scope of a variable is not the same as the lifetime of the variable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)#SCOPE-AND-EXTENT). Using the `static` keyword instructs the compiler that the **lifetime** of the variable is the whole running time of the program. But putting the variable inside a function body instructs the compiler that the **scope** of the variable is that function.

Comment: The local variable cannot be used outside the function simply because... it is local. It can be actually accessed outside the function where it is defined if it returns some way its pointer.

Comment: By declaring a static variable within a function, you are saying two things: 1) that the variable is specific to the function itself (scope), that needs it in order to work; 2) that the function need the variable mantains its value across different calls (lifetime)

Comment: Static and global variables may be stored in the same place in memory but they are two separate things entirely. The operating system differentiates between the two so you cannot treat a static variable like a global variable and vise versa.

Comment: Oh well, I would have avoided to bother writing those comment if I noticed that someone wrote the same thing better. @user3386109, transform it in an answer.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni the busybee already did, feel free to upvote that answer. I was just posting the link to the wikipedia page (link-only answers are frowned upon).

Comment: You should have seen this error message: *untitled2.c:9:2: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)*   You have to pay attention to warning and error messages.

Answer (score 4):

You need to differentiate between the **scope** and the **lifetime** of a variable.

In simple words:

"scope" means the region of your *source code* where the variable is known *to the compiler*. If a variable is (by the rules) not visible to the compiler, it will refuse to compile accesses to it.

"lifetime" means the time beginning with the allocation of memory for the variable until the moment the memory is assigned to another variable or released. A `static` variable lives as long as the program runs. A non-`static` variable lives just as long as its scope is in control.

However, just because both scope and lifetime of a variable are "finished", that does not mean that the memory disappears. The physical cells are still there, and they keep their last contents. That's why you can program functions that return a pointer to some local variable, and retrieve that variables contents *after both the scope and the lifetime* of the variable are gone. This is a fine example of a beginner's confusing issue.

Consider a compiler for an embedded processor like the 8051. Granted, a quite old and simple machine, but a good example. This compiler will commonly put local variables in its data segment. But to use the limited memory space (128 bytes in total, including working registers and stack) the *same* memory locations are re-used for variables with non-overlapping lifetimes. Eventhough, you could access any memory from all of the program.

*Now, language lawyers, start picking on me. ;-)*

Comment: It should be noted that, while it's perfectly okay to return (and use) a pointer to a **static** local variable, it would be undefined behavior to use a pointer to a non-static local variable this way. So yes, you can write code which tries to access a variable after its lifetime has ended, but that's forbidden by the standard. In a case like that, a particularly smart compiler might decide not to emit assembler instructions for that access, or anything that depends on it (though i don't know if any compiler actually behaves this way)

Answer (score 0):

A variable in C consists of two things:

- A name, called an *identifier*. An identifier has a *scope*, which is a region of the program source code in which it is *visible* (may be used).
- A region of storage (memory), called an *object*. An object has a *lifetime*, which is a portion of program execution during which memory is reserved for it. This is also called *storage duration*.

For a variable declared inside a function, its identifier has *block scope*, and the identifier is visible only from its declaration to the `}` that closes the innermost block it is in. (A block is a list of statements and declarations inside `{` and `}`.)

Inside a function, declaring a variable with `static` makes its object have *static storage duration*, causing it to exist for all of program execution, but it does not change the scope of its identifier. The object exists throughout program execution, but the identifier is visible only inside the function.

When another function is called, the object still exists (and it can be used if the function has its address, perhaps because it has been passed as a parameter). However, the identifier for the variable is not known inside the source code of other functions, so they cannot use the identifier.